# How to use imported constant

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a file of constant variable like

```
export const root="http://localhost:3000";
export const noderoot="http://localhost:5000";
```

I had imported it in my file like

```
import {root,noderoot} from '../../../assets/admin/js/constant.js'
```

and i am trying to use it like

```
axios.get({noderoot}+'admin/')
```

but it's getting as object not as string and i am not getting my data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't be hard in yourself, sometimes the answer is so simple, just remove the {}

```
axios.get(noderoot+'/admin/')
```

Comment: It's saying undefined to noderoot

Comment: do a console.log(noderoot) , to see if you get the correct value

Comment: MAYBE you should add +     '/admin'   and it isn't the fault of the variable

Comment: It's saying undefined in console as well

Comment: try checking your path if it is correct or not, the code is correct the path may be a problem

Comment: If i am looking in network it's giving me http://3000/admin/undefined/admin

Comment: my conclusion :  ../../../assets/admin/js/constant.js    this is not correct , check it again

Comment: No that path is correct because if i remove something then it's giving me error of module not found

Comment: can you tell me how to use listen in axios.get

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem in here https://stackblitz.com/fork/react   i will help 100%

Answer (score 0):

constant

```
export const root="http://localhost:3000";
export const noderoot="http://localhost:5000";
```

imported in other files

```
import {root,noderoot} from '../../../assets/admin/js/constant'
```

**Ways to access**

```
axios.get(noderoot+'/admin/')
```

Or

```
axios.get(`${noderoot}/admin/`)
```